# Java - invokeLater will not run

Tags: java, swing

I followed a tutorial to create a messenger. I typed the code correctly, and I have pretty basic understanding of what everything does.

Although, I do not end up with the same result. Here's the code:

---

```
public class Server extends JFrame{
    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input; 
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection;

    //constructor
    public Server(){
        super("Coffee Messenger");
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                    userText.setText("");
                }
            }
        );
        add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane());
        setSize(300,150);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
    //set up and run the server
    public void startRunning(){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100);
            while(true){
                try{
                    //connect and have conversation
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();
                }catch(EOFException eofException){
                    showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
                }finally{
                    closeCrap();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //wait for connection, then display connection information
    private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
        showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect...\n");
        connection = server.accept();
        showMessage("Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }
    //get stream to send and receive data
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
    }
    //during the chat conversation
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
        String message = "You are now connected!";
        sendMessage(message);
        ableToType(true);
        do{
            //have conversation
            try{
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                showMessage("\n " + message);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                showMessage("\n idk wtf that user sent");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
    }
    //close streams and sockets (application)
    private void closeCrap(){
        showMessage("\n Closing connections...\n");
        ableToType(false);
        try{
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //send message to client
    private void sendMessage(String message){
        try{
            output.writeObject("SERVER - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\nSERVER - " + message);

        }catch(IOException ioException){
            chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: Cannot send message.");
        }
    }
    //updates chatWindow 
    private void showMessage(final String text){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    chatWindow.append(text);
                }
            }
        );
    }
    //sets the ability to edit the textfield
    private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    userText.setEditable(tof);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
__
```

---

When I start the application from my main method, the string "Waiting for someone to connect" (from the waitForConnection method) does not show up. I believe the problem lies within the showMessage method. Am I using it wrong? If I replace the invokeLater method with a simple system.out.println();, the project runs exactly as planned.

Sorry, I'm a bit inexperienced so it might be something really simple. Thank you very much in advance.

(credits to thenewboston for making these tutorials)

Comment: Where is your main method?

Comment: And why are you not adding your chatWindow JTextArea to the JScrollPane? Your GUI appears to be displaying an empty JScrollPane for no reason. Wouldn't it be better if you had, `add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));`? I'll make that an answer as it is a key problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
chatWindow = new JTextArea();
add(new JScrollPane());
```

your GUI is creating a JTextArea, chatWindow, but adding it to nothing that displays it, and instead your GUI displaying an empty JScrollPane. It would be much better if you had,

```
chatWindow = new JTextArea();
add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
```

This way text sent to the JTextArea has a chance of being displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess I missed that part. Really appreciate it!